# Clock syncronization between Azure compoenents/services

Tags: azure, datetime, clock, azureservicebus

I couldn't find anywhere about the clock synchronization between different instances of an App Service and also between App Service and other Azure services (e.g. Azure Storage, Service Bus etc.)

What I need to know is if there is any grantee that if we take DateTime.UtcNow on two instances of App Service (website), to which degree they will be comparable.

Also to which degree the clocks of App Service (website) match with other Azure infrastructure. As currently I think there is miss-match in seconds. Take a look at following example of what we are currently seeing in our system on azure.

DateTime.UtcNow when message was posted to Service Bus: **2017-11-28T09:13:02.6400373Z**

DateTime.UtcNow when message is recieved: **2017-11-28T09:13:04.5372848Z**

The value of EnqueuedTimeUtc in the message: **2017-11-28T09:13:05.6578427Z**

As you can see the receive time is before enqueue time, which seems wrong. Also I suspect similar desparitiy in Timestamp on entities stored in Azure Table Storage.

Comment: I guess you answered your question: don't assume clocks are synchronized

Comment: Time is hard. Time zones are harder. Synchronization is... You guessed it!  Think about for a moment. What kind of effort would it take too synchronize all those machines just in a single data center.